# Error when replacing a value in a data frame with NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, na

Say I have this dataframe `z`:

```
x <- c("NS","NS",NA) 
y <- c("yes","yes","b") 
z <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

> z
     x   y
1   NS yes
2   NS yes
3 <NA>  b
```

I just want to change the values that contain the `"yes"` element to `"a"`. If I do this I get an error:

```
z[z$x=="NS","yes"]<-"a"
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, z$x == "NS", "yes", value = "a") : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
```

Because for some reason I am getting the dataframe with NA even though I only subset by `"NS"`. If I remove the `NA`, I get another error:

```
na.omit(z[z$x=="NS","a"])<-"no"
Error in na.omit(z[z$x == "NS", "a"]) <- "no" : 
  could not find function "na.omit<-"
```

Comment: Maybe `z[z$x=="NS", "y"] <- "a"` ? Or maybe `z[ z$y == "yes", "y"] <- "a"`

Comment: when you use `z[z$x=="NS","yes"]<-"a"` you try to assign "a" to the collumn "yes"  and the rows  `z$x=="NS"` what you want is `z[z$x=="NS","y"]<-"a"`

Comment: also you'll probably have a problem to replace "yes" by "a" anyway as currently `z$y` is a factor. take a look at parameter `stringsAsFactors`. Also, because of the `NA` in `z$x` it is probably better to use `%in%` instead of `==`

Comment: This is a toy example, but when I read my data I use stringsAsFactors = FALSE. Don't think that is the problem

Comment: You should also put it in your toydata so it is a representative example. The first problem is the one mentionned in the first 2 comments

Comment: @DOWUDA : I really don't see the difference between what you're showing and what I did. You jsut changed the `"yes"` for `"y"` ?

Comment: "y" is the name of a column, "yes" isn't

Comment: @JavierM88 "yes" is a value in 2 cells, "y" is a column name

Comment: `z[z$x %in% "NS", "y"] <- "a"` should do (if you used `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`)

Comment: @DAWUDA, OK  you're right. Oddly I changed it and keep getting the same NA error

Comment: @Cath Yes, it worked! I really don't understand how to use %in% if you provide an answer with the explanation I could marked it as answered

Comment: because %in% "disregards" NA while `==` is puzzled as to what to do with it ;-)

Comment: @Cath Thanks! I like it when programmers anthropomorphice (is that a word?) computers

Comment: could you please make the question more clear as if your problem is just to modify the value of "y" from "yes" to "a" or if the question is how to handle missing values in "comparisons" ? thanks

Comment: As I'm absolutely unable to vote for any answer based on what you're trying to achieve can you cleart this: Do you wish to filter only on `x` column value or on both `x=="NS"` **AND** `y=="yes"` ?

Comment: For information, as is I did vote to close as unclear. I'll withdraw if you [edit] to clear that up in plain english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is to specify the variable name correctly, that is with the name and not the value (probably just a typo in your question): `"y"` and not `"yes"`.

Then another problem arises when you use `==` and it tries to think of what to do with the `NA` in the third row:

```
x=="NS"
[1] TRUE TRUE   NA
```

hmm, should it be kept or not ? It is neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`... so it just gives an error as it cannot "decide".

While, using `%in%` (which is actually `match(x, table, nomatch = 0)`), we get:

```
x %in% "NS"
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

There you go, `NA` doesn't match the value `"NS"` so it returns 0, or, in `logical`, `FALSE` : we shouldn't keep it.

Thus, to get what you want:

```
z[z$x %in% "NS", "y"] <- "a"
z
#     x y
#1   NS a
#2   NS a
#3 <NA> b
```

Comment: This fails for `z <- structure(list(x = c("NS", "NS", NA), y = c("yes", "no", "b")), .Names = c("x", 
"y"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: @m0h3n what do you mean this fails ? OP's problem is with the handling of `NA` basically and, while you seem to rely on the OP "words" to find the condition to turn `y` values to `"a"`, I rely on OP's code. For now, noone can know which is the real condition but actually, this is not the subject that matters in this Q... (and if the condition was on the value of `y` well OP wouldn't have any NA problem to begin with...)

Comment: I'd rather to leave the judgment to other users.

Comment: @m0h3n actually, it's more a clarification from OP that is needed but anyway

Answer (score 0):

To make it short, I would use:

```
x <- c("NS","NS",NA) 
y <- c("yes","yes","b") 
z <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))

z[, c('y')] <- ifelse(y == 'yes', 'a', y)
```

Comment: actually the question is on the rows where `x` is `NS`...

Answer (score 0):

Why not this simple:

```
z[!is.na(z$x=="NS") & z$y=="yes", "y"] <- "a"

#      x y
# 1   NS a
# 2   NS a
# 3 <NA> b
```

Comment: actually the question is on the rows where `x` is `NS`...

Comment: but his problem was stated in the title : `Error when replacing a value in a data frame with NAs` so OP wants to know how to handle that

Comment: well, I still don't think `z$y=="yes"` is the correct condition and if it was there would be absolutly no reason to check for `NA` in `x`...

Comment: This fails for `z <- structure(list(x = c("AAAAAA", "NS", NA), y = c("yes", "no", "b")), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")` as `!is.na` on `FALSE` (`z$x=="NS"`) will return `TRUE`, and you'll replace the value, this sounds against OP's attempt in the question.

Comment: @Tensibai well, one can think of many samples for which any of the solutions proposed here might fail. The point is that the OP knows where the problem raised. That said, I'm no longer interested to follow this discussion.

Comment: All in all `is.na(z$x=="NS")` is strictly the same as `is.na(z$x)`. So wrong answer to me. To get an expected behavior from the `z$x=="NS"` you should AND the !is.na with it: `!is.na(z$x=="NS") & z$x=="NS"`. (sorry too much edits, missed parts)

Comment: And FWIW the equal above within is.na is still uneeded (bad copy paste from me) `FALSE & NA` is always `FALSE` (no need to know RHS value), `TRUE & NA` is still `NA` (can't guess if it give TRUE or FALSE): so proper filter would be `!is.na(z$x) & z$x<=="NS"` (the last part `z$y=="yes"` is up to question's author).